Issue with AOPS's solution2 to this year's AMC 8 problem
Here are the problem and solution of this year's AMC 8 math competition from the Art of Problem solving site (link),
Problem,

A group of frogs (called an army) is living in a tree. A frog turns
green when in the shade and turns yellow when in the sun. Initially,
the ratio of green to yellow frogs was $3 : 1$. Then $3$ green frogs
moved to the sunny side and $5$ yellow frogs moved to the shady side.
Now the ratio is $4 : 1$. What is the difference between the number of
green frogs and the number of yellow frogs now?
$\textbf{(A) } 10\qquad\textbf{(B) } 12\qquad\textbf{(C) }
 16\qquad\textbf{(D) } 20\qquad\textbf{(E) } 24$

Solution,

Solution 2
Since the original ratio is $3:1$ and the new ratio is
$4:1$, the number of frogs must be a multiple of $12$, the only
solutions left are $(B)$ and $(E)$.
Let's start with $12$ frogs:
We must have $9$ frogs in the shade and $3$ frogs in the sun. After
the change, there would be $11$ frogs in the shade and $1$ frog in the
sun, which is not a $4:1$ ratio.
Therefore the answer is: $\boxed{(E) \hspace{1 mm} 24}$.
-ILoveMath31415926535

Although this is a very easy problem, but the provided solution2 really puzzled me and doesn't make sense to me.
I believe that, since the ratio of the difference between the number of green and yellow frogs is $4:1$, the final solution should be of the form $4a-a=3a$ and yes the answer is $B$ or $E$.
But I don't understand the method used in solution $2$. I'm wondering if this solution is correct.

Multiple of $12$ is straight off wrong - it must be a multiple of $20=4\cdot 5.$ That answer is just wrong.

One correct solution is to solve the equations: $$\frac{g}{y}=\frac 31\quad \frac{g+2}{y-2}=\frac 41.$$ and then compute $g-y+4.$

(I mean, the answer is $24,$ but the argument given for that answer is just completely wrong.)

The weird thing about that answer is it argues (wrongly) tthat the number of frogs should be amultiple of $12,$ and thus eliminates some of the answers, but the question didn't ask for the number of frogs, so even if the number of frogs was a multiple of $12,$ we couldn't eliminate any of the answers.

Also, even though the total number of frogs must be a multiple of 20, the answer being asked for is the difference in the number of frogs, which at the end would be $\frac{3}{5}$ of the total number.  (So yes, it ends up being the case that the answer must be a multiple of 12, but it's not at all clear whether the given solution is concluding that correctly.)

@ThomasAndrews Thanks! Yes that really confused me too. It is strange to see this as an official answer of the site.

That answer is totally wrong. It merely accidentally picks the right answer from the multiple answers.
We can say the total number of frogs is a multiple of $20,$ but that doesn't let us eliminate any answers, since the question doesn't ask for the total number of frogs.
If you really want to apply this "eliminate answers first" approach, we can fix it.
If $g$ is the total green at the start, and $y$ to total yellow, then we are seeking $(g+2)-(y-2)=g-y+4.$
We can use that $g-y$ must be even and $g-y+4$ must be a multiple of $3$ to get $g-y+4$ is a multiple of $6,$ which lets us eliminate the same answers as in the wrong answer.
Then we need to eliminate $g-y+4=12,$ or $g-y=8.$ That equality, along with $g/y=3,$ gives $y=4,g=12$ and then $(g+2)/(y-2)=7\neq 4.$ So $12$ is not an answer.
That leaves $24.$

This approach to multiple choice questions - eliminate all but one solution, taking advantage that the remaining solution must be the correct one - can be very useful on tests.
But in this case, it seems much easier to just solve:
$$\frac gy=3,\quad \frac{g+2}{y-2}=4$$ and find $g-y+4.$

I dislike the approach taken by the official solution, and prefer to consider the total number of frogs, rather than the number of shady frogs.
Since the ratio started 3:1, the number of frogs must be a multiple of $~4.$
Since the ratio ended 4:1, the number of frogs must also be a multiple of $~5.$
Therefore, there are $~20x~$ frogs.
Suppose $~x = 1.~$
Then the change from 3:1 to 4:1 would cause the number of shady frogs to change from $~15~$ to $~16,~$ which is an increase in shady frogs of $~1.~$  This violates the constraint that $~(5-3) = 2.~$
Therefore, $~x = 2,~$ you started with 30:10 and ended with 32:8.
